# Repeat accessing array items every second in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

I am very new in Java. Say I have a `ArrayList` with 10 string items, what I am trying to archive are

1. Print each items every second.
2. When all items are printed, it will return to the beginning, repeating printing

Can you give me some ideas in Java

```
ArrayList<String> testAL = new ArrayList<String>();
Timer tickerTimer = new Timer();
TimerTask sendMessageTask = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {

    }
};
```

Comment: You can also think of using Thread.sleep(1000) to delay

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
try {
   for (int i = 0; i < testAL.size(); i++) {
     System.out.println(testAL.get(i);
     Thread.sleep(1000);
   }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And run your `TimerTask` from the main... Also you got a `Timer` that can execute the `TimerTask` run every X seconds...

Comment: Thanks. I tried this way. But printing did not repeat, any suggestion?

Comment: You need to loop over the execution of the run method the simple way: `for(;;)sendMessageTask.run();` but you need to work in the solution and improve it ;)